# Why chart don't show the added points?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, charts

I'm working with Visual Studio 2015, C#, WinForms.

I just added a normal chart from toolkit and changed type to line, then added the following code:

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "HH";
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Hours;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalOffset = 0;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IsMarksNextToAxis = true;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IsStartedFromZero = true;
DateTime minDate = DateTime.Today;
DateTime maxDate = minDate.AddHours(23);
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = minDate.ToOADate();
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = maxDate.ToOADate();
chart1.Series[0].BorderWidth = 2;
for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++)
{
    chart1.Series[0].Points.AddY(i);
}
```

Output:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPTas.png)

Why the chart isn't showing the points added?

Comment: They probably are outside the limits of AxisX.Minimum and AxisX.Maximum. Do look at the values of the participating variables in the debugger. You'll see the double. That should clear up matters..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you miss X value (all point draw on X=0?)

```
chart1.Series[0].Points.Add(new Point(x, y));
```

EDIT: Was wrong.

Problem is that, your minX value on axes is 42475.0, check in debug. Maximum is 42475,9583333333. So you won't see your value for Xc<0,24). Change your X axe limes :)

Comment: Which limits should I use then?

Comment: Depends on what X axes you want?
chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(new Point(i+minDate.ToOADate(), y));
Then you should get X points from your axes minimum and interval of 1 (from i incrementation).

But even that your Axe is 42475.0 - 42475,9583333333 so range is less than 1. Reorganize that :)

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the XAxis range (minimum and maximum) to very large value, see the documentation for DateTime.ToOADate.

You may are also only setting the Y points value which appends these to you data points collection, the result of this will depend on the chart type you are using (which you don't specify).

Comment: I specified Im using line type, which range should I use then? The documentation doesn't help a lot to be honest.

Comment: That depends on what you want the axis to show, you might want to try a minimum of 0 and maximum of 23 as a starting point.